# riak error: [ERROR] [Node] (172.16.1.56:8087|0|0) failed healthcheck in createConnection

Tags: riak

I'm using Riak KV 2.2.6 in a single host. I need this for implementing APACHE TRAFFIC CONTROL which is my CDN platform. I need to connect from one of my server in APACHE TRAFFIC CONTROL to Riak server but I get this error message in my APACHE TRAFFIC CONTROL server:

```
`riak error: [ERROR] [Node] (172.16.1.56:8087|0|0) failed healthcheck in createConnection, err: read tcp 172.16.8.240:47638->172.16.1.56:8087: i/o timeout`
```

I've configured Riak using Let's encrypt SSL certificate and here is my configuration in `/etc/riak/riak.conf` for using SSL:

```
ssl.certfile = /etc/riak/certs/server.crt
ssl.keyfile = /etc/riak/certs/server.key
ssl.cacertfile = /etc/riak/certs/chain.pem
tls_protocols.tlsv1.1 = on
```

I've added all three SSL files in correct path but I get time out error which I mentioned abow.
Could you please tell me why I get this error message in Riak client?
Thanks in advance.